# Microsoft Teams App - pass team's culture to oauth backend provider in Tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have build a Teams application on Asp.net core and connected the oauth backend provider. At startup.cs, I dont know the Team's culture yet. Then I ask user to login and get the culture in my cshtml page. But I am not able to find a way to pass Team's cultutre to my oauth backend.The settings goes like this in statup.cs:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OAuthScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = RefreshTokenIfRequired
                };
            })
            .AddOAuth(OAuthScheme, options =>
            {                
                var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineApiSettings>(Configuration["settings"]);
                options.ClientId = settings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret;
                options.AuthorizationEndpoint = settings.AuthEndpoint;
                options.TokenEndpoint = settings.TokenEndpoint;
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth/callback");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

This is how login page constructed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loginV1() {
        microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
            microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then((context) => {
                login(window.location.origin + "/LoginPopup?culture=" + context.app.locale);
            });           
        });        
    }

    function login(url) {

        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const redirectUrl = urlParams.get('redirectPath');

        microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
            url: url,
            width: 600,
            height: 535,
            successCallback: function (result) {
                console.log("Login succeeded: " + result);
                window.location.href = "/" + redirectUrl;
            },
            failureCallback: function (reason) {
                console.log("Login failed: " + reason);
                window.location.href = "/" + redirectUrl;
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

and LoginPopup page is like below:

```
    [Authorize]
    public class LoginPopupModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

        public LoginPopupModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("LoginSuccess");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We are checking with engineering team if there is any way to pass Team's culture to my oAuth backend. We will inform you once we have any update. Thanks!

Comment: The solution I provided below only works on browser, not on Desktop and Mobile. @Prasad-MSFT could you please suggest any solution.

Comment: Generally, we provide that information in the app context. We refer to it as the locale: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=Json-v2%2Cteamsjs-v2#get-context-by-inserting-url-placeholder-values

Comment: You can insert the `{locale}` placeholder in your app's content or configuration URLs and Teams will replace it with the user's locale before loading the app. Alternatively, you can call the [getContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-1.12.1#@microsoft-teams-js-microsoftteams-getcontext) API after the page has been loaded and retrieve the locale from the response of the API.

Comment: yeah, I am doing exactly the same in LoginV1 function(see above). I am getting the context and passing to oauth provider. It works in Browser well but fails on Mobile and Desktop. The context doesnt passed in case of Mobile or desktop. Can you check the scenario at your end and confirm if you have the same behaviour?

Comment: We tried using below snippet but were able to get locale in context. `microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {         microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then((context) => {
            alert("origin:"+window.location.origin + "culture=" + context.app.locale);
        });`

Comment: No, this is not the issue.Please dont alert it. I am too able to get it like this. Pass it to oAuth provider using options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint. I get the value perfect till here. I can see in my logs. but the value doesnt get pass in case of Desktop and mobile.

Comment: Could you please share specific repro video along with deployed manifest, as we are not able to repro this at our end?